# Should I use EntityFramework with stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I'm building a ***new*** website using MVC and EF Code-First.

As I understand, EF dynamically created a full SQL command based on my changes. Surely, if I had lots of changes it would create a lot of SQL queries and commands.

It seems to me that I should boost my website's performance with reducing the traffic load as much as possible.

Is there a reason not to do so ?
Is there a major site out there that doesn't use stored procedures with EF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion Entity Framework is intended to be used with LINQ-to-Entities and the built-in change tracking including the automatically generated DML statements whereever you **can** and it has the backdoor to use Stored Procedures whereever you **must** - both with respect to performance.

If you are planning or forced to optimize every single millisecond by using Stored Procedures for really everything I don't see a point and benefit to use Entity Framework at all in your project. You might well use plain ADO.NET with direct SQL statements and Stored Procedures.